# I can't scroll my centralized page with display flex when I zoom it

Tags: html, css

Currently I'm making a periodic table with Html and Css, and I needed to centralize my page then I did:

```
page {
 display:flex;
 align-items:center;
 justify-content: center;
}
```

but, when I zoom it, I can scroll to top or down, but I can't scroll to right or left.

May you help me?

Answer (score 0):

try adding `min-width: min-content;`